# Solving $\cos(t)y' + y\sin(t) = \cos^4(t)$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I worked it down to the standard form of 
$Y' + \tan(t)y$ = $\cos^3t$ and found the integrating factor of $e^{\ln(\sec t)}$. This gets me to

$\int (e^{\ln(\sec t)}y)' $ = $\int e^{\ln(\sec t)}\cos^3t$

But I have no idea how to solve the integral on the right.

I tried breaking up the $\cos^3t$ into $\cos^2t \cos t\to\cos t - \sin^2t \cos t$, then distributing the $e^{\ln(\sec t)}$, but wasn't able to solve this, either.

Comment: What does $e^{\ln\sec t}$ equal?  It simplifies to something very nice for this problem.

Comment: Oh. WOW. My experience with math has been "if it was a snake, it would've bit me". Ok, so now the right side looks like $\integral sect cos^3t$, and I seem to be fumbling that as well. How can I simplify this? (Oh god i see that too now. Thanks so much and I apologize for not noticing these.)

Comment: The snake is still biting you...sec t = 1/cos t.

Comment: Yeah... :/ can't believe myself right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $e^{\ln(x)}=x$, so you can write

$$e^{\ln(\sec t)} \cos^3 t = \sec(t) \cos^3 t = \cos^2 t.$$

Comment: Ill accept this in a few minutes when the timeout clears. Thank you!